# jQuery Ajax load table not whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

## FIXED

My problem is resolved. My issue was not the jQuery command as much as i was using the same template as when first loading the page and the table included in that jsp page.

### Solution

MY solution:
Create a new template to be called on new page load name ControlTable. 
Create a new jsp file with only the table. Have it loaded with both templates.
when jquery is triggered call only the new template via the controller -> template -> jstl core

**Background**

1. I have a form that I fill in to create a website user login information.
2. When i enter the text into 'plantNo' and select producer from my Drop Down   list. i want it to load a table into after querying the servlet to get the data.
3. It is getting the data ( i can see via console) and retrieving the list.

**Problem**

The problem is the reloading of the table. It is reloading the whole webpage into the table. What am i doing wrong? I am new to jQuery and AJAX.

**jQuery function**

```
function getProdInfoData(variableIn){

var plantnumber=document.myform.plantNo.value.trim();
alert(plantnumber);

    $.post('Admin?page=createUser', {"plant_no": plantnumber },function(data){
         $('#pi').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
    });

}
```

**Create_User.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/ajax_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/create_web_user.js"></script>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  


<style type="text/css">
label{display: inline-block; width:120px; font-weight: bold;}
input{width:250px; height: 25px; font-size: 18px; margin-right:25px;}
select{width:250px; height: 25px; font-size: 18px; margin-right:25px;}
#pi tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: #dae5f4;
}
#pi tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #ccccc;
}

<h2> Create Website User Login</h2>
<!-- &nbsp is a non break line space  needed to offset for the asterisk in the required fields-->
<div id="reserve_form"><form name="myform" method="post" action="/Admin?page=create_user_confirm" onsubmit="return validateform(this.form)" > 

<div id="User_name"><p><label class="form"><sup style="color:red; font-style:bold, italic;">*</sup> User Name: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="uname" name="user_name" />
    <label class="form"><sup style="color:red; font-style:bold, italic;;">*</sup> First Name: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="fname" name="first_name" /></p></div>

<div id="User_pword"><p><label class="form"><sup style="color:red; font-style:bold, italic;">*</sup> Password: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="pword" name="user_pword" />
    <label class="form"><sup style="color:red; font-style:bold, italic;">*</sup> Last Name: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="lname" name="last_name" /></p></div>

<div id="Plant_no"><p><label class="form"><sup style="color:red; font-style:bold, italic;">*</sup> Plant or Prod #: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="plantNo" name="plant_no" />
    <label class="form">&nbsp; Farm Name: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="farnname" name="farm_name" /></p></div>




<div id="Acct_type"><p><label class="form"><sup style="color:red; font-style:bold, italic;">*</sup> Account Type: </label>
                     <select name="acct_type" id="acct_type_select"  onchange = "ShowHideDiv2(this.value)"  style="height: 25px;">
                        <option value=""> </option>
                        <option value=5>Producer</option>
                        <option value=15>Field Man</option>
                        <option value=2>Admin</option>
                     </select>

                     <label class="form">&nbsp; Email Address: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="emailaddress" name="email_address" /></p></div>

                     <div id="cntrl"><p><label class="form"><sup style="color:red; font-style:bold, italic;">*</sup> Control #: </label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="cntrlno" name="cntrl_no" />
                     </div>

<table id="pi" style="display: block" >
<tr id="header">
    <td>Control Number</td>
    <td>Producer ID</td>
    <td>Producer Name</td>
    <td>Producer Name 2</td>
    <td>Producer Name 3</td>
    <td>Plant</td>
    <td>Coop</td>
    <td>Federal Order</td>
</tr>
    <c:forEach items="${prod_ctl_sel}" var="pt" varStatus="i">
        <c:set var="background_color" value="#fff"/>
        <c:set var="border_color" value="black"/>
        <c:set var="v" value=""/>
    <tr class="producer_data" id="<c:out value="${i.count}_row"/>" >
        <td style="text-align:center;"><c:out value="${pt.prodCtlNum}"/></div></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.prodIdNum}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.prodName1}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.prodName2}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.prodName3}"/></td>       
        <td><c:out value="${pt.prodPlant}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.prodCoop}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${pt.prodOrder}"/></td> 
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

finally **servlet/controller**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

//_LOTS_OF_CODE_IN_BETWEEN
if(request.getParameter("page")!=null && !request.getParameter("page").equals("")){ 
            if(request.getParameter("page").equalsIgnoreCase("createUser")){ 
                /* NEW CODE to create  user */

                String updateID = info.getUserid();
                String prod_number_in = request.getParameter("plant_no");   
                AdminFunctions af = new AdminFunctions();
                ArrayList prod_control_select = new ArrayList();
                System.out.println("prond_num_in"+ prod_number_in);
                if(prod_number_in != null || prod_number_in != ""){
                    prod_control_select = af.getProdCtlNum(prod_number_in);
                    request.setAttribute("prod_ctl_sel",prod_control_select);
                 }
```

Since a picture is worth a 1k words here is a screen grab.

[Screen Grab of the webpage after (removed some database info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEDSw.png)

Comment: try this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax

Answer (score 0):

This code may be helpful for your problem.

```
function getProdInfoData(variableIn){

var plantnumber=document.myform.plantNo.value.trim();
alert(plantnumber);

$.post('Admin?page=createUser', {"plant_no": plantnumber },function(data){
     $('#pi').html('').append(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
});
}
```

Comment: Some elaboration goes a long way. The OP asked what they did wrong. Providing a solution that "*may*" be helpful helps nobody understand what the problem was in the first place, nor understand why the code you provide is a fix. I cannot stand answers that do not provide any explanations. It devalues the question.

Comment: How can check if we have not any dummy data ?

Comment: You're proposing a solution. You must have a reason for *why* it is one. Otherwise why propose it? The difference here is not whether it *is* a solution but *why* and you have not given an explanation.

Comment: the single quotes in the `.html(' ')` actually prevent anything from happening. I don't see any data refresh at that point no table or the whole webpage loaded into where the table is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `ajax` call, actually you are **sending** data throught **POST** method but you are sending a `parameter` in your `url` as well which is a only possible when using a `Get` method, your `url` `Admin?page=createUser` is wrong it should be simple in **POST** method,

> If you are **sending** data through **POST** method then you should send the parameters along with your object.

so make your ajax request like below

```
$.post('yourPage.php/Admin', {"page":"createuser","plant_no": plantnumber },function(data){
     $('#pi').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
});
```

> If you are **sending** data through **GET** method then you can send the `page` parameters along in your **URL** or using an **object**

```
 $.get('yourPage.php/Admin?plant_no='.plantnumber,function(data){
     $('#pi').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful in my understanding of jQuery GET and POST methods. However I still have the same issue... the whole page is loading in the spot the table is suppose to go. instead of me just getting the table loading.

Comment: I changed the post method to read: 

     `$.post('/AdminController', {"page":"createUser","plant_no": plantnumber },function(data){
     $('#pi').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
});`